# How can jump to next TextFormField when one is filled?

Tags: flutter, focus, textfield, textformfield

I am currently building the birthday page for my onboarding.

as you can see in the picture, i have created three textformfields in which the user can type in the day month and year(LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter = 2 for days and months, 4 for years).

How can i make it so when one textfield is filled with the required digits, e.g. 12 for Days, the focus will automatically jump to the next TextFormFiled month without the user clicking on anything besides the required digits.

thanks in advance!

[birthday page of onboarding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiKBf.png)

``````
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          dateComposition,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 7),
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(4),
          width: dateComposition == "Year"? 73: 55,
          child: TextFormField(
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            //Keyboardtype for numbers
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            //only numbers can be typed in
            inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
              FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
              LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(dateComposition=="Year"? 4 : 2),
            ],
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
            autofocus: true,
            cursorColor: kPrimaryMagentaColor,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: kTextIconColorDarkBlue),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              ),
              hintText: dateCompositionHintText,
              hintStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 18.0),
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 10,
                right: 10,
                top: 10,
                bottom: 10,
              ),
              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: kPrimaryMagentaColor,
                  width: 1.5,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
`````
``````

Answer (score 0):

for doing so, you have to assign `FocusNode()` to your `TextField()`, then on the `onSubmitted` method of your TextField, you have to `mySecondTextFieldFocusNode.requestFocus()`.

```dart
 FocusNode textSecondFocusNode = new FocusNode();

    TextFormField textFirst = new TextFormField(
      onFieldSubmitted: (String value) {
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(textSecondFocusNode);
      },
    );

    TextFormField textSecond = new TextFormField(
      focusNode: textSecondFocusNode,
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the property *textInputAction* and set it to *TextInputAction.next*,

```dart
TextFormField(
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
  ...
)
```